# Can not create a Stripe payment method from LWC

Tags: stripe-payments, salesforce, lwc

**Error is stripe.createPaymentMethod is not working in lwc? This method renderedCallback to load Stripe js from static resources in salesforce.**

```
async renderedCallback() {
  if (this.stripeJsLoaded) {
    return;
  }

  this.stripeJsLoaded = true;

  await Promise.all([loadScript(this, StripeJS)]);
  this.stripe = Stripe("pk......");

  this.stripeElements = this.stripe.elements();

  var style = {
    base: {
      color: "#32325d",
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
      fontSize: "16px",
      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#aab7c4"
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: "#fa755a",
      iconColor: "#fa755a"
    }
  };

  const cardElementContainer = this.template.querySelector('.card-element');
  if (cardElementContainer) {
    this.cardElement = this.stripeElements.create('card', { style: style, hidePostalCode: true });
    this.cardElement.mount(cardElementContainer);
  } else {
    console.error('Element with class "card-element" not found in the template.');
  }
}
```

**This method is to create payment method on stripe but not working. expected result should be payment method Id.**

```
async tsCreateCardOnStripe() {
  if (this.isStripeCardFound) {
    this.stripeDataCardId = this.paymentMethod.Stripe_Id__c;
    if (this.oneTimePay || this.defaultPay) {
      this.tsCreatePaymentOnStripe();
    } else if (this.subscriptionPay) {
      this.tsCreateProductsOnStripe();
    }
  } else {
    const billingDetails = {
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    };

    const payload = await this.stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: this.stripeElements.getElement('card'),
      billing_details: billingDetails
    });

    console.log('payload : ' + JSON.stringify(payload));
  }
}
```

**console.log('payload : ' + JSON.stringify(payload)); no log returns?**

Comment: Is there any error on the Console? If you a log before `const payload =` does it ever reach there?

Comment: Add error handling to the stripe.createPaymentMethod call to catch and log any errors.